Active Host user + Remote user in Windows 11 Pro
There is something I've been wondering for a couple of years.
Given the "workstation" nature of Windows Pro versions, theoretically multiple users should be able to log-in, in the same machine at the same time concurrently.
Here there were some options regarding this topic:
Can I establish a Remote Desktop connection to another user on the same computer?
Like RDP Wrapper. The thing here is that I'm not 100% confident, if this covers the scenario I'm thinking in:
1 user working on the computer physically (USB keyboard and mouse, for example)
+
Another user working on the same computer, remotely (RDP)
Why this? Only one reason: The machine I want to use has an RTX4090 GPU, which happens to be very useful for rendering purposes. Instead of having to buy two machines with this card, one card is sitting idle most of the time, but both users would like to use it, one present in the computer, and the second, remotely from a simpler computer without a big GPU
From what I've heard there is a licensing system, where you can pay exactly for this, concurrent users. But still, I'm not 100% certain if it covers this scenario.
I'm 1000% certain that multiple remote users can work remotely because I've done this in the past in a Windows 2003 server. And I'm 100% sure this can be achieved in any pro version. But as I said, everything I achieved was full RDP (2, 3, 4 or even 5 users through RDP all).
However, in this scenario, what I need is to keep active the host user while a remote user also works with it.
Has anyone found a solution to this scenario?

Consumer versions of Windows have never allowed multiple remote user sessions simultaneously. What you describe has only ever been supported on Windows Server. You say it’s possible on Windows Professional, but it actually isn’t available, there have been “hacks” that allowed that but I cannot in good faith suggest modifying system files in 2024.

@Ramhound Generally Windows server is used headless, does this feature works in WS? I would not even care to work with WS instead of W11 if I could achieve this.

Windows Server does support multiple remote desktop sessions, provided you pay for the necessary client licenses. However, I think you are overestimating the ability of multiple users within a single system to use a single consumer level GPU.

@Ramhound, yes, I know that WS support multiple remote sessions. The thing here if it supports, one remote and one host session. About the GPU, the thing is that most of the time stays idle. So it wont be used concurrently. For example: host user will be simply browsing while the remote is rendering. If the host is rendering, the remote won't be using the PC at all. Like using the GPU on demand but with the ability of not leaving the PC exclusively as a headless server for this purpose

I don't believe there is actually any difference between a user logged into the operating system and using RDP to access the system. If you were to RDP into a consumer version of Windows, were to look at the monitor of said system, it would show the system was logged in as the remote user. You could technically unlock the system, which granted might disconnect the remote session, but i suspect it wouldn't.

I happened to find this rdpwrap fork: https://github.com/sebaxakerhtc/rdpwrap
And it works perfectly with Windows 11, exactly what I was looking almost out of the box. In fact, I believe that regular RDPWrap also works with Windows 11 with the right tweaks (like the right INI file for the given version of termsrv).
I've been completely blown away with this solution. I will be testing for a couple of days, but it is precisely what I was looking for.
